# Got 404 error when changed siteurl via DB in Wordpress

Tags: permalinks, mysql, htaccess, site-url, home-url

The problem is that I have changed the `wp_options` table with site URL and home fields from `http://localhost/WordPress` to http://localhost/test

I get 404 errors or Object not found error.

What I need to do to make my page render correctly?

Comment: Hello Antony! After renaming you also changed in settings? Change and salve. Then check whether the .htaccess file has been generated/modified or not. Look at this https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

Comment: The problem is not in that. I have changed the url manually in database via wp_options table but my site gives me 404.

Comment: WordPress Single install or Multisite? Restarted apache?

Comment: Wordpress is single install. Yep, restarted apache but the same 404. Maybe something with xampp or apache configs. I do not know.

Comment: rewrite_module is enable in the Apache configuration?

Comment: I am on xampp, how to make it using xampp?

Comment: Yep LoadModule with rewrite is existent instruction on  my httpd.conf file on xampp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105325/discussion-between-daniel-gross-and-antony-lapitskiy).